# Looking for Apple IIe emulator disk images

Tags: images, emulator

Could someone tell me where I can find disk images for the Apple IIe emulator called AppleWin I think. I really searched everywhere but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

This software is getting harder and harder to find! I have a couple of plastic tubs full of Apple II software on the original disk, and the original Apple II machines to go with them, but I don't have any of it in electronic format.

Maybe try here? ftp://ftp.apple.asimov.net/pub/apple_II/images/

If all else fails, there's AppleSoft BASIC built in! :-) You can type any program at the ] prompt, and then type RUN. Ctrl-C will break execution. Ahh, the good old days before Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that emulator for windows here:

http://applewin.berlios.de/

Comment: The thing is, I allready have the emulator but I couldn't find resources with .dsk image files which I could use in the program. Images with old Apple IIe - compatible applications, os, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of resources, including disk archives, here:
http://stason.org/TULARC/pc/apple2/emulator/index.html.

This one seems to be mostly games:
www.virtualapple.org/2listS.html.

Answer (score 0):

There is an image called MASTER.DSK that comes with the protramme. I just copped it to the desktop and renamed it GAMES.DSK. If you same programmes from the emulator while it is running you cam have as many as you like. Remember to mount the image in one of the disk drives. This is done by clicking on the icon tho the right of the emulator when it is running. The you simply select the image you want and click open.